# What are the @rules called in CSS?

Tags: css

In CSS, you got @import, @media, etc. But what are these @rules called? Just like : are called pseudo classes and # are called id's. (I know this question is really rough and stupid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called **at-rules** and **conditional group rules**:

> **At-rules** are CSS statements that instructs CSS how to behave. They
> begin with an at sign, '@' (U+0040 COMMERCIAL AT), followed by an
> identifier and includes everything up to the next semicolon, ';'
> (U+003B SEMICOLON), or the next CSS block, whichever comes first.

Furthermore:

> Much like the values of properties, each at-rule has a different
> syntax. Nevertheless, several of them can be grouped into a special
> category named conditional group rules. These statements share a
> common syntax and each of them can include nested statements—either
> rulesets or nested at-rules. Furthermore, they all convey a common
> semantic meaning—they all link some type of condition, which at any
> time evaluates to either true or false. If the condition evaluates to
> true, then all of the statements within the group will be applied.

`@import` is an example of an **at-rule** while `@media` is a **conditional group rule**.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/
- https://compat.spec.whatwg.org/#css-at-rules

Comment: Then what's the difference between an at-rule anda conditional group rule?